# How do you configure TMDA for virtual email addresses if the configuration references ~/.tmda?

Tags: linux, email, postfix

I'm trying to configure TMDA and it says to edit `~/.tmda/config` file, but where is that file for virtual email addresses?

http://tmda.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/moin.cgi/PreConfiguration

> TMDA can support any recipient delimiter character though, just make sure you use the same character for your RECIPIENT_DELIMITER setting in ~/.tmda/config.

My Postfix has virtual email address like this in `vmailbox`

```
name@domain.com domain.com/name/
```

And configured in `main.cf`

```
virtual_mailbox_domains = domain.com domain2.com domain3.com
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/mail/vhosts
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmailbox
```

Comment: So all your mailboxes are owned by the same user?  How are you forwarding their email through TMDA in the first place?

Comment: Yes, mailboxes are owned by `vmail` user. 'main.cf': `virtual_uid_maps = static:497; virtual_gid_maps = static:510`. 'passwd': `vmail:x:497:12:virtual mail users:/var/spool/vmail:/sbin/nologin`. I don't use TMDA yet. I don't know how to configure it. http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html#virtual_mailbox